# AngularJS interpolates array to string inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

TL;DR
directive interpolates array as string..
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZwV8jmi0tUTgezWlEq3S?p=preview

Here is code:
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="foo">

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body data-ng-controller="FooCtrl">
    <ul data-foo="{{foo.bar}}">
      <li data-ng-repeat="bar in foo.bar">
        {{bar}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
!(function(ng) {
  'use strict';

  FooCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
  function FooCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.foo = {
      bar: [
        'foo',
        'bar'
      ]
    };
  }

  function FooDirective() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        model: '@foo'
      },
      link: function($scope) {
        var watcher = function(model) {
          console.log(model, typeof model);
        };

        $scope.$watch('model', watcher, true);
      }
    };
  }

  ng.module('foo', [])
    .controller('FooCtrl', FooCtrl)
    .directive('foo', FooDirective);
})(window.angular);
```

Why do I have "typeof model" string instead of array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind the actual array of the parent scope use:

```
scope: {
  model: '=foo'
}
```

When using `@foo` you are just binding the result of the expression `{{foo.bar}}`. In your case the string interpretation of the array `foo`.

**Addition**

As an alternative you can call an expression on the parent scope from the isolated scope when you use the `&` symbol:

```
scope: {
  model: '&foo'
}
```

and evaluate it in your directive using:

```
model().bar
```

Comment: I don't wanted to use two-way binding because of additional watchers.
So, looks like I have to use it.

Comment: @Miraage I added another option using `&`